# Why does my componentDidMount() function not get fired when I refresh the page, but does work when I first land on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Essentially, when I first navigate to the page (/postjob) from any other page, or hit ctrl+s in my text editor, it seems that the componentDidMount() function fires, but when I refresh the page, I don't think the function fires. But I am confused as to why, since I thought this lifecycle method fires every time the component mounts, and when I refresh, that counts as a re-mount.

Here is my componentDidMount function:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { user, getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth0;

    const callback = (data) => {
      this.setState({
        userProfile: data
      })
    }

    
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getUserMetadata(user, getAccessTokenSilently, callback);
    }
  }
```

Here is my getUserMetadata function, which is in another JS file:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the full users profile, including all metadata, from auth0
 * @param {Object} user the user object provided by Auth0
 * @param {Function} retrieveToken getAccessTokenSilently function from Auth0
 * @param {Function} callback function to call after userMetadata has been retrieved
 */
const getUserMetadata = (user, retrieveToken, callback) => {

  retrieveToken({
    audience: `https://${domain}/api/v2/`,
    scope: "read:current_user",
  })
  .then(accessToken => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://${domain}/api/v2/users/${user.sub}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      }
    }

    axios.request(options)
      .then(res => callback(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

And here is my component state:

```
this.state = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
  skills: [],
  otherSkills: '',
  price: '',
  paymentForms: [],
  userProfile: null,
};
```

The thing I am concerned with is userProfile. On the first render, the getUserMetadata function should be run, which fetches a token, and then sends a GET request using axios, which returns the data and then sets userProfile to the data. It does so correctly when I first land on the page (as described above) but when I refresh, userProfile is null. I have no idea why, but my current suspicion is something about my callback function, with the improper scope?

Comment: My guess is that `componentDidMount` is actually called, but because you are reloading the app from this page `this.props.auth0` hasn't been set/updated yet and `isAuthenticated` is still false, so user data isn't fetched. Can you show a more complete code example? This component and the parent component rendering it and passing the `auth0` prop? In most cases you just need to also implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method so when state higher up updates then this component can respond accordingly.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, you were right in that the props had not been updated yet so isAuthenticated was still false, but it becomes true later. So I added a componentDidUpdate method and it works. I read the docs and I'm still wondering why I have to wrap my method in a conditional? It seems that componentDidUpdate runs whenever props or state changes, so why can't I just call my method directly?

Comment: If you are referring to that `getUserMetadata` function, remember that `callback` is updating state, so any unconditional state updates from a lifecycle method that responds to state updates will create an infinite loop. In other words, `getUserMetadata` would result in updating state which would result in calling `componentDidUpdate` which would call `getUserMetadata` and update state and trigger `componentDidUpdate`.... repeat ad nauseam.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Thanks!